# Start and run a given number of Tasks at Microsoft Azure Worker Role

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, asynchronous, azure-worker-roles

At my Run() method I call an async method:

```
public override void Run()
{
   RunAsync(_tokenSource.Token).Wait();    
}
```

I know that I can't use an async/await here, so I have to call Wait() at the end of RunAsync().

That RunAsync() method is the following:

```
public async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
   await Process(token);
}
```

This Process method contanis the infinite loop cycle and starts many Tasks depends on the queue message.

My problem is that I would like to start this Process() method for example 5 times paralel. Every Process() method has got a very long running time and has to do a lot CPU intensive computing. I would like to set the number of this Task to 5. If every Task is busy, the user have to wait a little longer to execute the request. Buti if one of the Tasks are finished the executing, it can start to process the next request. I tried several ways to implement that kind of logic without success.

I tried to implement that like:

List tasks = new List();

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   tasks.Add(Process(token));
}

foreach (var item in tasks)
{
   item.Start();
}
```

But the Tasks won't start at all.

How can I implement that kind of logic?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your tasks are starting, but actually calling `Start` will cause an exception. Also, your code is not waiting for them to complete, so the worker role would stop.

This should work:

```
List tasks = new List();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  tasks.Add(ProcessAsync(token));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

You may also want to consider using TPL Dataflow.